# stm32f0 uart1 rx interrupt

Tags: stm32, serial, uart, interrupts, stm32f0

I have stm32f030f4p6 Microcontroller and using iar Compiler , 
library cmsis ,
After confige Uart1 
the RXNE , FE and CMF bits return 1 whereas not recieve or send was done
if I dont set RXNE bit to 0 thats Stuck on interrupt routine
And that recieve nothing
here is my Uart Config:

```
  USART1->BRR = 0x1388;
  USART1->CR1 = USART_CR1_UE | USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE;
```

and GPIO config
and Nvic:

```
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART1_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPriority = 0;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

and the register after this 2 line

```
  USART1->BRR = 0x1388;
  USART1->CR1 = USART_CR1_UE | USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE;
```

[image]

rx tx connected to sim800 module and its answer to AT Properly

thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a debugging question abandoned without followup for three years

Comment: This question is old and will probably be closed. You can get it reopened if still of use to you by adding more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use CMSIS only some kind of mix of everything.

No NVIC structures needed. (of course the rest of the usart init is needed)

```
USART1->CR1 = USART_CR1_UE | USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_RXNEIE; 
NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
```

in the interrupt routine you need to clear the RXNE flag by reading from the data register - `USART1 -> RDR`

Comment: thank you.but the interrupt still didnt work.i can see data from sim800 module sending to micro.i try to clear the RXNE flag manually :USART1->RQR |= 0x0008; and by reading the RDR register too.RXNE return 0 but never return 1 again.

Comment: You can? I do not understand what your problem is

Comment: PS you FE flag which indicates the frame error. You have wrong usart configuration.

Comment: thank you peter.sorry i can see data by uart to usb module.but micro do nothing.PE is 0 and FE is always 1 after config.i try to using SPL lib for uart config now

Comment: i config it with SPL,my code: `usart.USART_BaudRate = 9600;
  usart.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
  usart.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
  usart.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  usart.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
  USART_ITConfig(USART1,USART_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);  
  USART_Init(USART1, &usart);
  USART_Cmd(USART1,ENABLE);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);` after sending one character , get into the uart routine.in the routine i sending 's' and set RXNE bit to 0.its Never happens again.AsTE0.sending ATE0